# Matching a value from a table to a set of existing corrections (on a grid) by distance

Tags: python, pandas, matching, kdtree

I've been looking at several ways to match values and I'm not sure what the best option is in this case. What I have are 1) and input table of 4 columns and 316 rows: x,y,dx,dy:

```
-233200.0 -233200.0  -19.4   21.4
-212000.0 -233200.0  -23.7   23.8
-190800.0 -233200.0  -26.8   26.4
-169600.0 -233200.0  -39.0   33.5
-148400.0 -233200.0  -39.0   33.5
-127200.0 -233200.0  -46.0   38.4
-106000.0 -233200.0  -47.2   38.2
-84800.0 -233200.0  -49.3   38.8
-63600.0 -233200.0  -50.8   35.8
-42400.0 -233200.0  -49.4   32.1
```

My second table is a similar beast of length 529: index, Kx,Ky,Kdx,Kdy:

```
 1    -3995   213531  -44.1   32.7
  2   -25446   213433  -48.6   37.0
  3    -3175   169047  -44.7   19.7
  4     -831    40968   -8.7  -15.1
  5    -2771   147269  -33.1    1.3
  6   -43705    82864    3.5   -5.3
  7   -24925   191012  -46.2   30.4
  8   -25982   236253  -58.1   48.8
  9   -46318   191012  -48.2   31.2
```

The goal is, for each of x,y (316 points), I'd like to find the closest point Kx,Ky and return a list that is x,y,dx,dy,Kx,Ky,Kdx,Kdy.

Reading these files in I can create a distance dmin that is 316 points long with:

```
dmin=[]
for i in range(len(xf)):
    for y in range(len(xK)):
        dist=np.sqrt((x[i]-xK[y])*(x[i]-xK[y])+(y[i]-yK[y])*(y[i]-yK[y]))
    dmin.append(np.min(dist))
```

However, if I try to return xK,yK,dxK,dyK I get 316 values that only cover half of range from the x,y original 316 grid of points.

```
for i in range(len(xf)):
    for y in range(len(xKnn)):
        dist=np.sqrt((x[i]-xK[y])*(x[i]-xK[y])+(y[i]-yK[y])*(y[i]-yK[y]))
    dmin.append(np.min(dist))
    ymatch.append(yKnn[i])
    xmatch.append(xKnn[i])
    dxmatch.append(dxKnn[i])
    dymatch.append(dyKnn[i])
```

I have looked at putting this into pandas as I could join the tables if I could write an index that would update at Kx,Ky when dmin is true.

```
d={'x': x, 'y': y, 'dx': dx, 'dy': dy}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

dKnn={'xK': xK, 'yK': yK, 'dxK': dxK, 'dyK': dyK}
dfKnn=pd.DataFrame(data=dKnn)
```

However, here I ran into problems as I couldn't define a dKnn column from the smaller data frame.

Finally I have been searching the scipy.spatial.KDTree routine but as it seems to be designed to accept only a single array I haven't been able to find a way to get it to return a matched dxK,dyK. It seems like the pandas dataframe is the most hopeful way forward but I have gotten very stuck so any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your problem.  Could you elaborate on this: However, if I try to return xK,yK,dxK,dyK I get 316 values that only cover half of range from the x,y original 316 grid of points.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing a k nearest neighbor classifier where `k=1` and the number of classes is each of the 316 rows.

This example will be trivial because of the small number of example rows you have posted, but you can extend it easily.  First, load the data into a pandas dataframe.  (You will read from a file, but for this example, I am constructing them by hand).

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = '''-233200.0 -233200.0  -19.4   21.4
-212000.0 -233200.0  -23.7   23.8
-190800.0 -233200.0  -26.8   26.4
-169600.0 -233200.0  -39.0   33.5
-148400.0 -233200.0  -39.0   33.5
-127200.0 -233200.0  -46.0   38.4
-106000.0 -233200.0  -47.2   38.2
-84800.0 -233200.0  -49.3   38.8
-63600.0 -233200.0  -50.8   35.8
-42400.0 -233200.0  -49.4   32.1'''.split('\n')

s2 = ''' 1    -3995   213531  -44.1   32.7
  2   -25446   213433  -48.6   37.0
  3    -3175   169047  -44.7   19.7
  4     -831    40968   -8.7  -15.1
  5    -2771   147269  -33.1    1.3
  6   -43705    82864    3.5   -5.3
  7   -24925   191012  -46.2   30.4
  8   -25982   236253  -58.1   48.8
  9   -46318   191012  -48.2   31.2'''.split('\n')

df1 = pd.DataFrame([list(map(float, x.split())) for x in s1], 
    columns=['x','y','dx','dy'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([list(map(float, x.split())) for x in s2], 
    columns=['i','kx','ky','kdx','kdy'])
```

Now we can use `KNeighborsClassifier` from scikit-learn.  We set k equal to 1 (`n_neighbors=1`) since you only care about the closest point.  Train the model on the first data frame using row index as the class, and then predict the points of the second data frame.  After that, you just merge on the predicted class.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
knn.fit(df1[['x','y']], df1.index)
closest_index = knn.predict(df2[['kx','ky']])

# assign the closest index to df2
df2['closest_df1'] = closes_index

# merge the two dataframes, drop the useless columns
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_on='closest_df1').drop(
    ['i','closest_df1'], axis=1)

# returns:
         x         y    dx    dy       kx        ky   kdx   kdy
0 -42400.0 -233200.0 -49.4  32.1  -3995.0  213531.0 -44.1  32.7
1 -42400.0 -233200.0 -49.4  32.1 -25446.0  213433.0 -48.6  37.0
2 -42400.0 -233200.0 -49.4  32.1  -3175.0  169047.0 -44.7  19.7
3 -42400.0 -233200.0 -49.4  32.1   -831.0   40968.0  -8.7 -15.1
4 -42400.0 -233200.0 -49.4  32.1  -2771.0  147269.0 -33.1   1.3
5 -42400.0 -233200.0 -49.4  32.1 -43705.0   82864.0   3.5  -5.3
6 -42400.0 -233200.0 -49.4  32.1 -24925.0  191012.0 -46.2  30.4
7 -42400.0 -233200.0 -49.4  32.1 -25982.0  236253.0 -58.1  48.8
8 -42400.0 -233200.0 -49.4  32.1 -46318.0  191012.0 -48.2  31.2
```

The output here is pretty boring because ALL of the matches are to the same row.  But the idea works.